# Как замокать response в pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Каким инструментом и как лучше замокать ответ, получаемый функцией от сервера? Посоветуйте чем вы пользуетесь для таких случаев.

Ну, например какая-нибудь такая функция

```py
def my_func():
    products = requests.get('http://some-site.ru/some-page').json().get('products')
    return products
```

```
def test_my_func():
    products = my_func()
    assert products[0].get('name') = 'Холодильник'
```

Вот как сделать так, чтобы в `products` попали тестовые данные в тесте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо инкапсулировать:

1. Можно вынести адрес хоста куда-то вовне, чтобы во время теста составлять другой URL. Попутно поднять мок-сервер по этому адресу, чтобы отвечал нужными данными.

```py
HOST = 'http://some-site.ru'
if mode == 'test':
    # как вариант
    HOST = '127.0.0.1:8800'

def get_products():
    products = requests.get(f'{HOST}/some-page').json().get('products')
```

2. Вариант попроще и в то же время мощнее, создать базовый класс по работе с данными, в одном его наследнике будут отправляться реальные запросы куда нужно, а в другом специальном классе-наследнике будут возвращаться фейковые данные для тестов. При этом, здесь тоже можно легко провернуть работу с полноценным мок-сервером.

```py
class DataProvider:
    # тут можно определить абстрактные методы и т.п
    pass

class ServerDataProvider(DataProvider):
    def __init__(host):
        self.host = host

    def get_products():
        products = requests.get(f'{self.host}/some-page').json().get('products')
        return products

class FakeDataProvider(DataProvider):
    def __init__():
        pass

    def get_products():
        products = [ ... ]  # любые фейковые данные
        return products

if mode == 'test':
    data_provider = FakeDataProvider()
else:
    data_provider = ServerDataProvider(host='http://some-site.ru')
```

`mode` можно ставить как где-то в других модулях, так и на основе переменных окружения или консольных аргументов (например, банально ища там подстроку `test`).

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая библиотека [`requests-mock`](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Использование вполне прозрачное - регистрируй желаемые ответы на комбинации URL + method. Пример теста для `my_func`:

```
def test_my_func(requests_mock):
    payload = {'products': [{'name': 'Холодильник'}]}
    requests_mock.register_uri('GET', 'http://some-site.ru/some-page', json=payload)
    products = my_func()
    assert products[0].get('name') == 'Холодильник'
```